# How can I loop through data in mySQL and join tables based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a scorecard application and I have 3 separate MySQL tables that I want to `INSIDE JOIN` based on the `Round_ID` (keeping all rows with the same `Round_ID` together).

I've figured out how to join based on this, but now my idea is to use a WHILE loop to iterate through each `Round_ID` entered in the database and create a separate JOIN table for each one (1,2,3 etc) so I can have a separate scorecard table for each round entered. I decided to put the statements in a procedure so I can call it later on easier. So far this is what I have -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_scorecard()
BEGIN
DECLARE increment INT;
DECLARE maxRound INT;
SET increment = 1;
SET maxRound = (SELECT MAX(Round_ID) FROM Course_Played);
WHILE increment <= maxRound
BEGIN
SELECT Player_Scores.Round_ID, Players.Player_ID, Players.Player_Name, Player_Scores.Player_Score, Course_Played.Course_ID, Course_Played.Course_Name 
FROM Players 
INNER JOIN Player_Scores 
ON Players.Player_ID = Player_Scores.Player_FK 
JOIN Course_Played 
ON Course_Played.Course_ID = Player_Scores.Course_FK
WHERE Round_ID = increment
SET @increment = increment + 1;
END
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But the code does not work. I keep getting a "check syntax error" and can't figure out where it went wrong. (As a side note, I am new to SQL and new to programming in general). I am also using phpMyAdmin if it matters.

Also, using a loop for this really the best way to accomplish this? I looked at cursors but don't know if that would be applicable in this situation...

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that a cursor or iteration is needed for this.  You should clearly explain the logic you want to implement, provide sample data, and desired results.

Comment: You're never incrementing `increment`. `SET @increment` should be `SET increment`.

Comment: The syntax error is because you forgot the `;` after `WHERE Round_ID = increment`

Comment: But I agree with Gordon that you don't need the loop. Just use `ORDER BY Round_ID` to get all the rows for the same round together.

Comment: `create a separate JOIN table for each one` Eh? That doesn't sound good. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The real problem here is that you're trying to apply procedural thinking to relational logic. The 'best' solution is to design a schema in which data tables represent a type of entity, not an instance of one.